# ActionScript: How to sort a class vector based on int

Tags: class, vector, actionscript, integer

I have a vector of TestClass objects that I would like to arrange in ascending order based on integer of each TestClass object. How would I do this?

Main Method:

```
public class testSave extends Sprite
    {
        public function testSave()
        {
            var testVector:Vector.<TestClass> = new Vector.<TestClass>;

            testVector.push(new TestClass(5, "Testing"), new TestClass(2, "HelloWorld"), new TestClass(7, "Ohai");


        }
    }
```

TestClass

```
public class TestClass
{
    public function TestClass(testi:int, tests:String)
    {
        this.stest = tests;
        this.itest = testi
    }

    public var stest:String;
    public var itest:int;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no `sortOn` for `Vectors` but there is a sort. So if you do this:

```
public function testSave():void {
  var testVector:Vector.<TestClass> = new Vector.<TestClass>;

  testVector.push(new TestClass(5, "Testing"), new TestClass(2, "HelloWorld"), new TestClass(7, "Ohai"));

  testVector.sort(function(a:TestClass, b:TestClass):Boolean {
    return a.itest > b.itest;
  });

  // confirm the vector is now sorted
  for (var i = 0; i < testVector.length; i++){
    trace(testVector[i].itest);
  }
}
```

your vector will sort. `Vector.sort` takes a sorting function, it compares the two values and then figures out how to swap them when iterating through the array...

Checking if a is greater than b will result in ascending order.